# Hide 0 when using select count

Tags: php, mysql

below is script for count comments. This worked but now I want when the comment 0, it just show comment, not 0 comment.

Any suggestions ?

```
<?php
            include "con_config_hapshout.php";

            $query3 = "SELECT COUNT(comment) FROM comment WHERE msg_id='$id'";
            $result3 = mysql_query($query3);

            while($total = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
                            echo "$total['COUNT(comment)'] comment";
                        }

            ?>
```

Comment: a query which does JUST a count with no grouping will only ever return a single row. There's no need for a while() fetch loop.

Comment: There's a little used thing called the `if` statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
        include "con_config_hapshout.php";

        $query3 = "SELECT IF(COUNT(comment) = 0, '', COUNT(comment)) AS comment_count
                   FROM comment WHERE msg_id='$id'";
        $result3 = mysql_query($query3);

        while($total = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
                        echo "$total['comment_count'] comment";
                    }

?>
```

Comment: ya that's what OP wants in case of 0 comments.

Comment: @Omesh nice... thanks for your helps. now working good. :)

Answer (score 1):

Group the result by the column name.

```
SELECT COUNT(comment) 
FROM comment 
WHERE msg_id='$id'
GROUP BY comment
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcd72/6)

Answer (score 0):

You're mis-using PHP strings - array key references in double-quoted strings SHOULD NOT be quoted, unless you use the `{}` syntax.

```
echo "{$total['COUNT(comment)']} comment";
      ^---                     ^--
```

Or better yet, alias the count in your query so you don't have to use such ugly array keys later on in PHP:

```
SELECT COUNT(comment) AS cnt ...

and

echo $total['cnt'];
```